# Find and replace a duplicate value in pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df in pandas:

[image]

I need to find the duplicate value, in this case the number 1 in the index 2 and apply the formula ma.trunc(ma.pow(x,2))+1 and after replace the value result in the index 2 where the number 1 was.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate all of the duplicates with the [duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) command. Note that keep="first" (default value) will prevent the first occurence from being marked as a duplicate.

```
is_dup = df.duplicated(subset="Enrollment", keep="first")
```

Then you can apply a custom function to the values that are duplicated with the [where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) functions.

```
my_func = lambda x: ma.trunc(ma.pow(x,2))+1
df["Enrollment"] = df["Enrollment"].where( ~is_dup, df["Enrollment"].map( my_func ))
```

Comment: awesome!!! thanks @Leo! that did the trick, thanks so much!